# What is the solution to getting around this React problem?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, yarnpkg

It happens when i run npx create-react-app in the terminal?
  if so do you know anyway i can get around this problem.
 I need to add more detail.

```
npx create-react-app my-react-app
```

> ```
>    npx: installed 1 in 2.024s
>     The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined
>     C:\Users\nbatr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\index.js
>
>     Creating a new React app in C:\Users\nbatr\bookmark-app\my-react-app.
>
>         Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
>         (node:7828) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental
>     Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...
>
>    yarn add v1.12.3
>     (node:3716) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental
>     [1/4] Resolving packages...
>     [2/4] Fetching packages...
>     error https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@xtuc/long/-/long-4.2.1.tgz: Extracting tar content of undefined failed, the file appears to be corrupt: "Unexpected end of 
>          data"info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about 
>       this 
>        command.
>
>
>  Aborting installation.
> ```

```
yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom react-scripts --cwd
```

> ```
>   C:\Users\nbatr\bookmark-app\my-react-app has failed.
>
>   Deleting generated file... package.json
>    Deleting generated file... yarn.lock
>     Deleting my-react-app/ from C:\Users\nbatr\bookmark-app
>     Done.
> ```

Comment: *It happens when i run npx create-react-app in the terminal?* – is this a question or a statement? If that's a question, how do you suppose we can answer that provided the current information? Please format the input and output properly (have I separated them correctly?) Describe in detail what you do, what you expect and what actually happens, otherwise, it's really difficult to help.

Comment: Thanks and appreciate it. I just restored my computer to factory setting and it worked just fine.